# What are the Shadow Children?

Tags: gene-wolfe, the-fifth-head-of-cerberus

In Gene Wolfe's loose trilogy of novellas *The Fifth Head of Cerberus*, the middle story (*"A Story" by John V. Marsch*) is the one which gives us the most direct insight into the lives of the so-called 'abos' or Annese, the original indigenous inhabitants of Sainte Anne. The story focuses on the twins Sandwalker and Eastwind, but the Shadow Children, mysterious person-like creatures who dwell on Sainte Anne together with the people, also get a lot of page time.

**Who or what are the Shadow Children?** When they talked about having come from another world, I assumed they were humans who had somehow had their form taken from them by the Annese, and that this explained the humanoid form of the Annese in this story. But in the third story, *V.R.T.*, it seems as though the splashdown at the end of this story really was the first arrival of humans on Sainte Anne ... so where did the Shadow Children come from, why are they so insubstantial now (if they're not human, were they always that way?), and what is their relationship to the Annese?

<sub>Even though I've now finished the whole trilogy, there are still things to be understood and mysteries to be unravelled! This reflects the depth and subtlety of the stories and the world Wolfe created. Perhaps I should reread the second one.</sub>

Comment: It's been a long time since I've read it, so there could be something that rules out this speculation. But could the Shadow Children be the ghosts of the original indigenous inhabitants of Sainte Anne? Or of the earliest human settlers, who went native? Or both? They seem very ghost-like, and many other works of Wolfe contain ghosts (most notably *Peace*, which was written at around the same time).

Comment: @PeterShor I think Sandwalker and his kin *were* some of the original indigenous inhabitants of Sainte Anne, and the earliest human settlers hadn't arrived yet (as I mentioned in the question, this story ends with what seems to be the first arrival of humans on Sainte Anne). But that conclusion is mostly based off some of the info in the third novella - while reading the second one itself, I thought exactly the same as you. It may be deliberately ambiguous, like many things in these stories. Maybe answering this question will give you an excuse to reread them? ;-)

Comment: I think they're ghosts. In the third story, VRT can see the Shadow Children on their expedition, while John V. Marsch can't. If they were real, wouldn't Marsch have been able to see them? Further, the middle novella was supposedly written by one of the book's characters, and I don't see why its chronology has to be consistent.